# Suppress a group header's contents after the first instance of the Group is displayed

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Here's the challenge:

I would like to Hide/suppress a group header's contents every time the group appears after the 1st time.  The group header may appear on a page more than once.

What would the suppress formula be for my "Group Header #2a"?

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The formula to use is: GroupNumber > 1